# Why CSS link behave weird?

Tags: html, css, sass

[image]

This is my file structure. When i type code like these

```
background: url("../../images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg");

background: url("./../../images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg");
```

browsers don't load image but when i type like this

```
background: url("dummy-text/../../images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg");
```

the image is loaded.

Also when i follow the codes that don't work in the browser in vscode, vscode gets me to the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd never used scss, but as I understand, some component/plugin in VS Code will transpile SCSS into CSS, and put the resulting file uin the **~/css** folder.

So, your CSS should be `background: url("../images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg");`, since booth the browser and VS Code should resolve that URL relative to the **~/css** folder.

This URL can be read as: "From current folder (CSS) go up to its inmediate parent ("base-apparel-comming-so...) and then enter in the *image* folder and get the file named *bg-pattern-desktop.svg*"

### Why the *dummy* example also (kind of) works:

The URL in `background: url("dummy-text/../../images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg");` also works because that url, resolved relative to **~/css**, gives the same result as `background: url("../images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg");`.

Answer (score 1):

Your scss compiles and gets stored in `css` folder. As I can see from folder structure, It should have path like

```css
background: url("../images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg");
```

Because actual css will be used from css folder and image folder is one level outside from css source dir.

Answer (score 1):

In SCSS, our code is converted to CSS and in our HTML file we are linking to our CSS file. When it comes to images and external resources we must not link path relative to our SCSS file but to our CSS file.

So you should use  `background: url(...)` property relative to the CSS file within your css folder.

That should become : ' `background: url('./../images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg')` Assuming your CSS file is right within you css folder.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a path that's relative to the `_responsive` file that you probably import in `main.scss`,

```
background: url("../images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg");
```

When you import a file, the URLs should be relative to the importing file :)